# Let VB read certain area in text file, change it and save it

Tags: vb.net

I want my program to read a certain part of a huge txt file, change one value and save the file again.
The file that needs editing looks like this:

```
168575 = {
    name="Hidda" 
    female=yes
    dynasty=9601
    religion="catholic"
    culture="german"
    father=168573
    960.1.1 = {
        birth=yes
    }

    1030.1.1 = {
        death=yes
    }
}
```

My VB program takes the IDs from the blocks it has to change from another textbox like this.

```
31060
106551
106550
168575
40713
106523
106522
106555
```

As you can see, the number I want changed is in the middle of the textbox, the code I use to get the number from the line and look for it in the huge file is

```
Dim strText() As String
strText = Split(chars.Text, vbCrLf)
```

and later

```
If line.Contains(strText(0) & " = {") Then
TextBox1.AppendText(line & Environment.NewLine)
```

To form a code like:

```
Dim strText() As String
    strText = Split(chars.Text, vbCrLf)

    Label4.Text = strText(0)



    Dim line As String = Nothing

    Dim lines2 As Integer = 0
    Using reader2 As New StreamReader("c:/dutch.txt")
        While (reader2.Peek() <> -1)

            line = reader2.ReadLine()

            If line.Contains(strText(0) & " = {") Then
                TextBox1.AppendText(line & Environment.NewLine)

            End If


            lines2 = lines2 + 1

            Label2.Text = lines2



        End While
    End Using
```

Naturally, this only writes in a textbox the line that it found, how do I get the whole code with that IDs I take from 1 textbox, change the culture to another value and save it again? And repeat this for all the IDs in a textbox? Im not a coding legend but this has been bothering me for ages now :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues to consider here.  If you're dealing with a large text file as a "database" and you wish to edit only parts of it without affecting the other parts, then you may wish to investigate editing it as a binary file instead of as a text stream.  This has several downsides, however, since it means that you have to be aware of how big your records are and deal with things like padding.

If you can spare the disk IO and RAM (I don't know how huge you mean when you say huge) it would probably be vastly easier to simply load the entire file into an array or List(Of String), find the line representing the person, seek a few lines below that for the field you want (you said culture), change that field in the array or List, and then just resave the entire array or List back to a text file.  This would make it fairly easy to do inserts and you wouldn't have to worry about padding, mostly you'd just have to worry about the line endings and the file encoding (and the amount of disk IO and RAM).

Finally, I would suggest that using a custom format text file as a database is generally a "bad" idea in 2014 unless you have a **really** good reason to be doing that.  Your format looks very similar to JSON - perhaps you could consider using that instead of your existing format.  Then there would be libraries such as JSON.Net to help you do the right thing and you wouldn't need to do any custom IO code.